# Attempt to present * whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am using the following code in `AppDelegate` to display a popup window within the app when a button is selected, i will eventually move this to a label hyperlink but just testing currently.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("test") as! ViewController
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
    storyboard.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = storyboard.view.frame
    storyboard.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(storyboard)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(storyboard, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The first time i select a button this works correctly, however on all subsequent button presses the following **error** is displayed.

> 2016-10-28 11:27:40.551 testfordeeplinks[20496:104536] Warning:
>   Attempt to present 
>   on  whose view is not
>   in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who stumbles across this in the future, this is how i resolved;

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = storyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

`rootViewController` doesn't necessarily refer to the view controller that is currently visible. For example, if you utilise a `UINavigationController`, `rootViewController` will hold a reference to that navigation controller which in itself is buried deep in the view hierarchy and hence when you try to present a view controller on it get an error. What I would recommend doing is grabbing the last view controller in `navController.viewControllers` and presenting your popup on that. See the following code:

```
let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
if let navController = appDel.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    if let visibleVC = navController.viewControllers.last {
        visibleVC.presentViewController(storyboard, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Give that a try and let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks Jacob, this returns the following error: 
Downcast from"UIViewController" only unwraps optionals, did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: I'm not seeing an error so I'm guessing you just forgot to paste it? :P

Comment: Downcast from"UIViewController" only unwraps optionals, did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: Oops my bad, I guess that's what happens when you try and remember exact syntax off the top of your head! See amended answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it doesn't seem to get past the first if statement though, so the view controller never loads, any thoughts?

@Jacob King

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`? because this answer will not work if the initial view in your flow is not a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response here, there was a view controller as i built a quick test app and forgot to add one, but after adding, i'm still getting the following error, have added code in app delegate below

`if let navController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            print("gothere1")
            if let visibleVC = navController.viewControllers.last {
                print("gothere")
                visibleVC.presentViewController(storyboard, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }`

Comment: That code should NOT be in the `AppDelegate.swift`, the project will not compile. It needs to be in the view controller that you want to show the popup from.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, the code seems to compile correctly. 

So you think this should be place in viewDidLoad on the viewcontroller that launches the popupviewcontroller?

Comment: Not in the `viewDidLoad` but wherever you want the new view controller to show. For example if you had a button and pressed it, you would place the above code in the outlet action for that button.

Comment: Hey Jacob, thank you again for your help on this, still struggling as placing it here gives the same error, would it be easier for me to send over the project file to you? Not a problem at all if you haven't got time to look into this.

Comment: Think i have resolved this now, i'm using 

`let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = storyboard`

Comment: There is a good to fair chance that I meant to type that in the answer rather than what is there... Good spot! I'm glad you resolved your issue.